# Connecting to the windows server 2003 using telnet in java

Tags: java, telnet

How can i connect to the windows server 2003 using telnet in java?
can you share if there is any links related to connection establishment using telnet?

Answer (score 2):

TELNET protocol is basically a interactive TCP/IP socket connection. You can use the java.net.Socket and connect to certain port (default port is 21 for TELNET protocol).
You can use this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) from Oracle as a starting point.

If you are looking for the protocol specification, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) provides quite resourceful of the list of RFCs that defines TELNET protocol. It's getting more hairy though, as it covers a lot of stuffs you probably don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Net includes an implementation of the Telnet protocol:

http://commons.apache.org/net/